# Using Arduino and Motor Shield

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, arduino-motor-shield

I am a beginner in Arduino.I want to connect 2 motors to Arduino. 
Do I require a motor shield?And if yes please tell why?
Also can i use an amplifier to increase the voltage for the motors?

And one last important question, I have just seen the motor shield's pic. Does it restrict arduino's pin usage? I mean we can't use the arduino pins if we use the motor shield right?

PS: I am talking about this model: SLAEX039 L293D Motor Shield

Thank a lot

Answer (score -1):

Yes. To use standard D.C. motors, you must use a motor shield or the L239D chip. This is mainly due to motor noise, and control to run the motor at different speeds and directions. Also you get very easy to use libraries!

Comment: Can we use amplifiers then?

Comment: **Please don't recommend the L293 (or L298)** these are horribly antiquated, lossy devices which cause users no end of problems.  One should pick modern motor shield with an FET bridge instead, for example the ones with the TB6612FNG.  **Additionally, the basic explanation of this answer is wrong** - the need is not due to "motor noise" or directional control but rather the required **motor current**.   H-bridges have basically the exact same output structure as ATmega pins, but are built to handle the required current and possible voltage range, while ATmega pins are not.